# Advice on requirejs dynamic loading of modules or use optimization/bundle tool in my situation

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js

I'm building a new web application that will consist of totally different interfaces/user experiences depending on what TYPE of user has just authenticated/logged in. Lets call these users Admins & Delegates.

Admins and Delegates have completely different functionality in this application. Only a small subset of my modules will be used by both. It's essentially two different client applications hooked up to my backend.

Should I create two different build files with the `RequireJS` optimizer, and then inject either of them into the page depending on what the server returns when the user performs a login? Or should I focus more on requirejs's dynamic module loading and just load the modules I need when I need them (thus running into a lot of extra http requests :/)

Answer (score 2):

We have a Backbone app, that shares a lot of views and models, but not all clients have all navigation points, and some models behave differently.

So first we have a single require entry point and a single require.config for every client.

**Bootstrap-client1.js**

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/cfe/app',
  paths: {
    'common/ViewA': 'clients/client1/ViewA',
    'common/ModelB': 'clients/client1/ModelB',
    'common/ColletionC': 'clients/client1/CollectionC'
  }
});

requirejs([
  'common/App',
  'common/BaseSetup'],

  function(app, BaseSetup) {
    $(function() {

      BaseSetup.start();

      app.start();
    });
  }
);
```

So later on when we use a shared View that requires `ModelB` this will replaced with our `client1/ModelB` implementation.

For production we build a single compiled version for every client with the r compiler and change the source of the `data-main` attribute in the html file when the client request the html file.

Comment: this sounds like a pretty good solution. My only difference is I'm trying to make the authenticate/login page a part of the application. That is, no page refresh after the user logs in. I could create two optimized build files that contain all of the js dependencies of each client - but how would I go about loading these after my login action completes?